# Partial refresh hides date picker icon

Tags: xpages

I'm using radio buttons to select between two criterias. If I click on one of them, there'S a partial refresh to a panel containing a date field with a date picker. If I switch between the two radio button criterias, the date picker icon disappears and there's only a simple edit box left.

Here's the code of the radio buttons:

```
<xp:radioGroup layout="lineDirection" value="#{docApplication.Productivity}" id="rbgProductivity">
   <xp:selectItem itemLabel="direkt" itemValue="1"></xp:selectItem>
   <xp:selectItem itemLabel="indirekt" itemValue="2"></xp:selectItem>
   <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelGeneral"></xp:eventHandler>
</xp:radioGroup>
```

That's the code of my date picker edit box:

```
<xp:inputText value="#{docApplication.RequestDate}" id="RequestDate">
   <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1"></xp:dateTimeHelper>
   <xp:this.converter>
      <xp:convertDateTime type="date" dateStyle="short"></xp:convertDateTime>
   </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

Before doing the partial refresh (it have to be more than one):
[image]

After doing the partial refreshs:
[image]

Can anybody help me with this? What do I have to do, to keep the date picker?

Comment: Hi M., what's the server base you're running this on (8.5.3 / 9 / 9.0.1)? Are you using extLib controls for the other 2 fields (numberSpinner & comboBox)? Or are those standard edit boxes bound to dojo attributes? - What happens if you change the radio's value once more, are the entry helper icons reappearing then?

Comment: Hi Lothar! Our Server is 9.0.1 and currently I'm not using extLib controls (well at least not for the date field, that's a simple edit box with a date picker function, and the other one is a dojo number spinner). If I change the value once more, it stays the same, so the picker function is no reappearing.

Comment: looks to me as if the entire csjs engine had quit working due to an error. What browser are you running currently? If it's FF then you should see those errors in its error console (I use the "Web Developer" addOn for quick access, but ther are other utils available); here you should be able to see where the error occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason, why this is happening, was a special circumstance, that I was using the view pick list control from [OpenNTF](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/View%20Picklist%20Custom%20Control). I've been using a lot of partial refreshes on the panel surrounding the pick list button and by that, I've killed the styles of the OneUI. Now I'm using a full update, which recreates those styles and now it's working.